# How to import a custom xml file into my EA model

Tags: enterprise-architect

The context of my use case is as follows:

I have a model of a robot that I have created in Enterprise Architect (15.1) primarily with SysML. I want my model to check a URDF file (which is itself an XML file) to determine whether attributes of the URDF model meet the requirements of my EA model.

In my EA model I have requirement 'Maximum Mass' that is satisfied by with a property 'mass', type Real, which is owned by 'Robot' block. In the URDF it has 'mass' attributes for each robot link (so in the XML hierarchy the 'mass' attribute is in robot:link:inertial).

My use case:
I want my EA model to import the URDF model in accordance with a XML schema. From there I should be able to sum the total mass according to the URDF model to give a derived value to my 'mass' property in the EA model and then compare that value to the requirement constraint to determine whether the requirement is verified or not.

If importing this urdf is not possible then is it possible to read the urdf file?

I took an example .urdf file and converted it to a .xsd file. In the Ribbon I then did Develop->Schema Modeling->Import XSD. I chose the 'UML Attributes' option under the 'Import XSD Elements/Attributes' Import Options header. Elements are stereotyped XSD{complexType,element,attribute} and the hierarchy looks to be in order. However, I don't know what to do next to import a urdf model in accordance with the created schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to import a random xml file into EA, not even if you have imported it's XML schema.

There are a number of file formats supported such as XMI, EMX/UML2, etc... but URDF is not one of them.

So in order to import the file you'll have to write your own automation in the form of a script, add-in or standalone program.

Before you can do that you'll have to determine how to translate your URDF file into EA concepts such as elements, attributes, connectors or tagged values.

Look here for more info on automation in EA: https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/automation_interface.html

Comment: Thanks Geert! Your video on scripting got me started on my own scripting journey.

Comment: In that case you might want have a look at my scripting library as well. https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library/ Lots of examples there.

Comment: I found a javascript parser for urdf files but it needs to import libraries - is it possible to run scripts inside of EA which import libraries outside of EA? If so then I could create a profile based on the XSD, build my logical system for the robot using class/blocks, run the script within EA that parses the urdf file and populate property values on the logical system. Do you think that workflow is in principle workable?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I'm not familiar with javascript, but you can definitely use COM objects from scripts inside EA, so I'm guessing external javascript libraries should be possible as well.